# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'aptTime' in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have an appointment model for patient to book appointment with a doctor, i used a custom user model for both doctor and patients, using `is_staff` and `is_patient` to differentiate them...

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
   
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='staff',
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    aptTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    pending_approval = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

in my views.py i am trying to set the patient to `request.user` and doctor to the context i passed through the url, so i have the `form_valid` method to create appointment like this...

```
class AppointmentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Appointment
    fields = ['aptTime']
    template_name = 'patients/Appointment-Createview.html'
    

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        form.instance.doctor = self.kwargs['pk'] #TODO change to doctor instance
        form.instance.aptTime = self.object.aptTime
        form.instance.patient = self.request.user
        form.save()
```

i got an error saying `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Appointment.doctor" must be a "User" instance. Internal Server Error: /patient/Appointment-Create/1/`
After searching around SO i was able to change my code to...

```
...Some code...

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        doc = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.doctor = doc #TODO change to doctor instance
        form.instance.aptTime = self.object.aptTime
        form.instance.patient = self.request.user
        form.save()
```

now i'm getting a new error saying

```
form.instance.aptTime = self.object.aptTime
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'aptTime'
```

I am using a model form, i don't understand why i'm getting this error.
Someone please help me out.

Comment: `self.object` is `NoneType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CreateView` has no `self.object`, this is always assigned `None`. You do not have to access this anyway, since this is already assigned to the object wrapped in the form, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class AppointmentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Appointment
    fields = ['aptTime']
    template_name = 'patients/Appointment-Createview.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.doctor_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.patient = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Your `Appointment` model however seems a bit *odd*. For example why not work with a nullable field `approved` that is `NULL`/`None` if it is not yet approved, `True` if the doctor approved, and `False` if the doctor rejected, this is probably better since otherwise the `pending_approval` can be `False` whereas `approved` can still be `None` resulting in a state that at least seems illogical:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='appointments',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
    apt_time = models.DateTimeField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=None, null=True)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `apt_time` instead of <s>`aptTime`</s>.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly, i will adjust my model as you suggested. I already use ```LoginRequiredMixin``` but had to remove it for simplicity while posting.